# Copy of GKSession object implementing copyWithZone

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copywithzone

I want to make a copy of a GKSession object and I implement copyWithZone as follow :

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

GKSession *kati = [[GKSession allocWithZone: zone] init];
kati=_currentSession;    
return kati;}
```

Nevertheless I don't take a copy of the initial object but a reference to that.

Am I missing something...;

The implementation of the copyWithZone is the way to make a copy of a GKSession object, or not?

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what your code is doing:

```
GKSession *kati = [[GKSession allocWithZone: zone] init];
```

You allocate a new `GKSession` object, and update the `kati` variable to point to the object.

```
kati=_currentSession;
```

You change the `kati` variable to point to another object.  This means the object you just allocated is leaked; you don't have a pointer to it anymore, but it wasn't ever deallocated.

```
return kati;
```

You return the value of the `kati` variable, which is a pointer to the `_currentSession` object.

This is clearly not what you want.  You want to create a new `GKSession` with the same underlying information as `_currentSession`, right?  In that case, I would start with:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
  NSString *sessionID = [_currentSession sessionID];
  NSString *name = [_currentSession displayName];
  GKSessionMode sessionMode = [_currentSession sessionMode];
  GKSession *kati = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:name sessionMode:mode]; 
  return kati;
}
```

Comment: Dave first of all thanks for your help. The statement to make a copy of a GKSession object using the copyWithZone is the following : myViewController.currentSession=[self copy]; Am i right?